# Disable TortoiseSVN project Monitor

Tags: r, windows, svn, tortoisesvn, rstudio

I installed TortoiseSVN on my work laptop (win 7 Ent.) and tried to integrate Tortoise with R-Studio. But because of some known issues (see [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200657436-TortoiseSVN-inside-RStudio-)), I did not take it further and disabled subversioning on R-Studio. Since then, when I start R-Studio client, the Tortoise Project Monitor opens up automatically and takes R-Studio into initialization stage until it crashes and I have to kill R-Studio client.

[image]
After playing around for few hours, I learnt that I have to open two instances of R-Studio to be able to run it. So, now, I open R-Studio and let it go into initialization stage and then in the meantime, I open another R-Studio and the 2nd one works fine; then I kill first one. But, it is kind of annoying as the trick does not work sometimes.

I uninstalled R-Studio and reinstalled it again and no change. I am afraid if I uninstall TortoiseSVN and then cannot install it again- as it is an open source and there is no support team to help in case of any trouble.

Wondering if anyone has any idea on how to disable project monitoring at all. I don't really need it at all.

Answer (score 3):

Project Monitor can be disabled in Project Monitor Options.

[image: TortoiseSVN Project Monitor Options]

Comment: from within RStudio? or from Tortoise options?

Comment: I have the same problem. Deactivating these option doesn't change the fact that Rstudio waits until I close tortoise monitor several times (monitor keeps starting over and over)